# How to reduce the rendering time

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to reduce the rendering time and I applied everything that was generally taught. Currently I'm using an RTX 2070 for the GPU in Cycles. Actually I have two of them and I can't even use them both in one computer because they are not SLi compatible. Does anyone know if there is any major difference between mine and an RTX 2080ti? Does it cut the rendering time in half a 2080ti? I'm willing to buy one if it shortens the time at least 50%. Let me know, thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86703/enable-dual-gpu-cuda-on-macos-seirra/86705#86705 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68257/does-blender-support-dual-gpu-rendering-if-the-two-gpus-arent-the-same/68269#68269

Comment: The simplest way to shorten rendering time is adding more GPUs .Two GPUs will render almost in half the time as one... Don't use SLI, you want to use each GPU to render a tile independently. The more GPUs you have the more tiles you can render simultaneously.  But rendering will take time no matter what. Read through  the many posts this same question has been asked already, there are plenty of tips on how to optimize a scene for faster rendering. Use the search box at the top of the page.